# pandas python round timestamp to nearest second

Tags: python, excel, matlab, datetime, dataframe

I want to replace certain time stamp values in a spreadsheet using pandas in python.

### **Background Info**

Spreadsheet A has time stamped values every 33 milliseconds (in the Time Stamp column). Also, it (in)conveniently skips every top of the second "S.000".

**SPREADSHEET A**

Time Stamp            | Location1   
5/4/2017 10:00:00.000 | 0.005430355 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.033 | 0.004475154 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.066 | 0.004958829 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.099 | 0.010678668 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.133 | 0.014313085 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.166 | 0.004182263 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.199 | 0.00232128 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.233 | 0.004263132 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.266 | 0.007513777 
. 
. 
5/4/2017 10:00:00.999 | 0.011229943 #always skips top of the second "S.000" 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.033 | 0.016148495 #always skips top of the second "S.000" 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.066 | 0.009239103 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.099 | 0.015364848 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.133 | 0.032139104 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.166 | 0.023679454 
5/4/2017 10:00:01.199 | 0.002503840

How can I use pandas to round every time stamp that has "X.999" to the nearest second? I want to

`see if a value is "X.999" in the to "Time Stamp" column
 if it is "X.999":
     change it to "X+1.000" / or round it up
 else
     leave the time stamp as it is`

Then keep repeating the above until I create a new set up time stamps for a new data frame. Or even better, replace the current dataframe time stamps with the new time stamps.

Comment: Questions about your overall approach are beyond the scope of stackoverflow. I suggest you cut this down to a specific question about pandas.

Comment: Ah, okay. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution so far...Took a long time, but it works for now.
Consider timestamps whose microseconds value were 9700000 (970 milliseconds) or higher, add whatever its difference was from 1 second to itself, then replace the time stamps with this new sum (always on the X.000 of a second).

Here is the code.

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
dfa=pd.read_excel("may2017.xlsx",sheetname=0)
dfb=pd.read_excel("logs.xlsx",sheetname=0, skip_rows=746243)
dfb = b.iloc[746244:754431] #got the index value range from trial and error
a = dfa
b = dfb
adummy = a
bdummy = b

for i in range(len(adummy.index)): #get the length of all rows
    #find the difference between each time stamp from 1 second
    dif = 1000000 - adummy.iloc[i]["Time Stamp"].microsecond
    #change microseconds to timedelta object for later
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=dif)
    #now check if this row timestamp is near a 1-second interval
    if adummy.iloc[i]["Time Stamp"].microsecond > 975000:
        #if near 1 second, 'round up' to the next second by adding tdelta
        tnew = tdelta + adummy.iloc[i]["Time Stamp"]
        #replace the time stamp in this row with the nearest second above
        adummy["Time Stamp"] = adummy["Time Stamp"].replace(adummy.iloc[i]["Time Stamp"], tnew)
        #print this new time to verify the dataframe got updated
        print(adummy.iloc[i]["Time Stamp"])
    else:
#else if the timestamp is not near 1 from the low side, do nothing
        pass
#Restart the loop
```

Output:

```
2017-05-04 10:00:01
2017-05-04 10:00:02
2017-05-04 10:00:03
2017-05-04 10:00:04
2017-05-04 10:00:05
2017-05-04 10:00:06
2017-05-04 10:00:07
```